Сервер OPC UA open62541 доступен только через localhost
Сервер, написанный с использованием open62541, почему он доступен только через localhost?
Я пробовал добавлять serverurls следующим образом
UA_String serverUrls[2];
size_t serverUrlsSize = 0;

UA_String_clear(config.serverUrls);

serverUrls[serverUrlsSize] = UA_STRING("opc.tcp://:48440");
serverUrlsSize++;
serverUrls[serverUrlsSize] = UA_STRING("opc.tcp://192.9.200.93:48440");
serverUrlsSize++;

retval = UA_Array_copy(serverUrls, serverUrlsSize,
        (void**)&config.serverUrls, &UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_STRING]);
if (retval != UA_STATUSCODE_GOOD)
{
    return retval;
}
config.serverUrlsSize = serverUrlsSize;

Но ничего не помогло, получается мне нужен сервер lds для доступа извне?
PS
Теги делать не дает, а тегов opcua и open62541 нет

Не знаю в чем была проблема, переделал проект с cmake на обычный проект visual studio, он спросил дополнительный заголовок arch/win32/ua_architecture.h и все заработало... Почему cmake его не спросил, непонятно...

Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — из очереди проверок

это бот? я автор вопроса...

лучше бы теги добавили opcua и open62541, на английском SO они есть...
